# No puedo desplegar imagene con vue usando axios

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axis

Hola estoy utilizando vue con axios para hacer request de informacion de una API y funciona con las datos como nombre, fecha pero cuando deseo utilizar lo con un `img src=""` no funciona :

html:

```
      <div class="container" id="app">
        <h3 class="text-center">VueNews</h3>
        <div class="columns medium-3" v-for="result in results">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-divider">
              {{ result.titulo_periodico }}
            </div>
            <div class="card-section">
              <img src="{{ result.photos[0].urls[2].original }}" alt="">
              <p>{{ result.photos[0].urls[2].original }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

app.js :

```
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    results: []
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("xxxxxxxxxx")
      .then(response => {
        this.results = response.data
      })
  }
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
alguna idea de como desplegar la img utilizando vue.

Answer (score 1):

Hola ya vi donde de encuentra el error se debe modificar la solicitud del `src`
con un `v-bind` hacer la solicitud de imagene con vue:

```
<img v-bind:src="result.photos[0].urls[2].original" alt="">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Siempre que cargues elementos dinámicamente debes usar el v-bind o usando simplemente : en cada elemento (src, alt) lo puedes usar en cualquier propiedad

```
<img :src="result.photos[0].urls[2].original" alt="">
```

Saludos